# Why Am I getting this error? Run-time 1004: Copy method of worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works fine on one machine but on another machine with the same Excel build it throws compile error "Copy method of worksheet class failed". Someone can explain to me why it occurs?

Subroutine functionality: Copy sheets from another workbook without opening source file.

```
Sub TestSub()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wsCount As Integer
Dim sourceFile As Workbook

Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Source\Source.xlsx")
wsCount = sourceFile.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To wsCount
sourceFile.Sheets(I).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'throws error here
Next I

sourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Working code below, thanks to @FaneDuru comment

```
Sub TestSub()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wsCount As Integer
Dim sourceFile As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Source\Source.xlsx")
wsCount = sourceFile.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To wsCount
sourceFile.Sheets(I).Copy After:=ws
Next I

sourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It throws after "Next j"

Comment: What "without opening source file" should mean?

Comment: Sorry, after "Next I"

Comment: "Without opening source file" means that I don't want to open/see workbook which I copy from.

Comment: But the above code is opening it. Otherwise, it could not copy its sheets. But forget about that... "After Next I" is a little strange error line positioning. Is it `sourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False'?

Comment: I reformatted code and now I am getting another error: "Copy method of Worksheet class failed" + I marked where an error occurs.

Comment: Are there protected sheets in the sourceFile workbook?

Comment: No, all sheets are unprotected.

Comment: There is no active sheet in 'ThisWorkbook', since the other workbook is active. You should declare and set the active sheet in discussion prior to opening of the new one. Try `Dim sh as Worksheet` followed by `Set sh = ActiveSheet` on top of `Set sourceFile = ...`. Then adapt the copying line in `sourceFile.Sheets(I).Copy After:=sh`.

Comment: @FaneDuru, it works! Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help!